# How do I look for the highest value of something in a txt file using Batch and set it as a value?

Tags: batch-file

I downloaded a file using curl and I am tyring to make batch find the highest value "paper-1.19.2-x" of x.
I wrote this code
`

```
@ECHO off
curl "https://api.papermc.io/v2/projects/paper/versions/1.19.2/builds/" --output builds.txt
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
For /f %%i in (builds.txt) do (
    for %%x in (paper-1.19.2-*.jar) do (
         set "line=%%~nx"
         set "line=!FN:paper-1.19.2-=!"
         if !line! GTR !max! set max=!line!
))
Echo paper-1.19.2-%max%.jar
```

I download the file and name it builds.txt then I try to read the file and look for the highest x value. but the output of this is simply
`paper-1.19.2-.jar`

I think what I am doing incorrectly is not reading the file correctly.
Any help?

**edit**

the builds.txt that is downloaded by curl is just a json file that i convert into txt, so it basically converts to 1 line txt file
and part of the code from it looks like this

`

```
{"project_id":"paper","project_name":"Paper","version":"1.19.2","builds":[{"build":112,"time":"2022-08-05T23:08:28.926Z","channel":"default","promoted":false,"changes":[{"commit":"bef2c9d005bdd039f188ee53094a928e76bd8e59","summary":"1.19.2 (#8250)","message":"1.19.2 (#8250)\n\n"}],"downloads":{"application":{"name":"paper-1.19.2-112.jar","sha256":"59e5b07dbffcbceeef15ebbe77ffcc8a56f58fdfcb2d3092be256c32a5c9588d"},"mojang-mappings":{"name":"paper-mojmap-1.19.2-112.jar","sha256":"f743f109522b2a21b290e9e9e8015e2e630ec74d6e7496a6bc31e5af34f2a4bd"}}},{"build":113,"time":"2022-08-06T23:30:43.315Z","channel":"default","promoted":false,"changes":[{"commit":"a15152e96a0c1f8b8f6792f4308e8077e01614d2"
```

the new batch code is
`

```
@ECHO off

setlocal EnableExtensions 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
curl "https://api.papermc.io/v2/projects/paper/versions/1.19.2/builds/" --output builds.txt
set "MaxNumber=0"
if exist "builds.txt" for /F "tokens=5 delims=-." %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "paper-.*\.jar" "builds.txt"') do if %%I GTR !MaxNumber! set "MaxNumber=%%I"
Echo %MaxNumber%
```

and it just out puts this
`

```
05T23:08:28
```

Comment: Certificate error, no download possible. Please paste (a relevant part of) the file into the question.

Comment: the link
"https://api.papermc.io/v2/projects/paper/versions/1.19.2/builds/" that i mentioned takes you to a json file

Comment: Please paste (a relevant part of) the file into the question. That way one person does the required work, not everyone who provides their time and expertise to solve your problem and the relevant data is available for all to see.

Comment: BTW, I've just ran your cURL command, and it turns out that there are a whole lot of instances of `"paper-1.19.2-*.jar"` on that single line output. Which one specificaly are you trying to capture? and for what reason do you need it?

Comment: @Compo I am looking to capture the highest one. so I can generate a download link of the latest build

Comment: Well the last instance of that over ninety thousand character single line JSON output is currently `256`, in my output, but as the first is `112`, and they appear to increment by `1`, you're already looking at 145 matches, and I'd assume that will change with each new version, _(up to `1.19.3.x`)_. It appears to me therefore that you need to find a more efficient way of performing this task.

Comment: A `for /F` loop cannot process lines longer than 8190 bytes/characters…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `build.txt` doesn't contain any line endings, so it's too big to be processed by a pure batch script.

You need a way to search the file (at best with REGEX). Powershell may provide an elegant solution, but if you are stuck with cmd/batch, you can download [jrepl.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) (written by [dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053/dbenham), a highly reputable member of this community), which is able to use full REGEX in batch:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('^<build.txt jrepl "paper-1.19.2-\d*" "" /match') do set "lastMatch=%%a"
echo %lastMatch%.jar
```

The REGEX pattern `"paper-1.19.2-\d*"` looks for any string `"paper-1.19.2-` followed by any number of digits (the parameter `""` ("replacement") is not used, but has to be present for syntax reasons)

Comment: Thanks for your input, just a final question, do I just inject the jrepl code in my bat file? or how do I use it.

Comment: like I showed you. If `jrepl.bat` is in another folder, you need to give it the full path (replace `jrepl` with `"F:\ull path\to\jrepl.bat"`

Comment: nvm i fixed it, and IT WORKS. thank you so much
you just forgot a percentage symbol 
`for /f "delims=" here>%a in ('^<build.txt jrepl "paper-1.19.2-\d*" "" /match') do set "lastMatch=%%a"
echo %lastMatch%.jar`

Comment: I don't understand how this code returns _the highest_ value... I think it returns _the last value_...

Comment: @Aacini: correct  (they are consecutive). It returns the *latest* file (advantageous in case of a rollback)

Answer (score 2):

There is a much simpler way to get the same result *for **your** data*:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

curl "https://api.papermc.io/v2/projects/paper/versions/1.19.2/builds/" --output builds.txt
call :readFile < builds.txt
for /F "delims=." %%a in ("!last:*paper-1.19.2-=!") do echo paper-1.19.2-%%a.jar
goto :EOF

:readFile
set "last=%line%"
set /P "line="
if not errorlevel 1 goto readFile
exit /B
```

Output:

```
paper-1.19.2-256.jar
```